# How do you get the index number of the item being selected?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to DisplayAlert the index number of selected item in the ListView, my code currently just display the item_code but I want to display the index number in the ListView, thanks a lot.

My .cs

```
lstView.ItemsSource = _sqLiteConnection.Table<ItemModel>();     
lstView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>        
{               
   await DisplayAlert("Selected ",((ItemModel)e.SelectedItem).item_code  
   + " was selected.", "OK");                     
};
```

My xaml.cs

```
<ListView x:Name="lstView">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell >
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
          <Label Text="{Binding item_desc}" />
          <Label Text="{Binding selling_price}" />

        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

View Model

```
public class ItemModel
{

    public string cost_method { get; set; }
    public string item_code { get; set; }
    public string item_desc { get; set; }
    public string item_group_desc { get; set; }
    public long item_id { get; set; }
    public string stock_item { get; set; }
    public string trnx_unit { get; set; }
    public decimal selling_price { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public Class Students
 {
      public int sid { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }  
 } 

 listview.ItemSelected += Lst_ItemSelected;

 private void Lst_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
  {
       var index = (listview.ItemsSource as List<Students>).IndexOf(e.SelectedItem as Students); // to get a index value or postion value 

       ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;

  }
```